# Is it possible to configure Spring Data Rest to use id as references instead of URI?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest, hateoas

The rest of my project was designed without hypermedia in mind. So association between entity is done via database unique id.

For example, an association is done via a

```
post /api/user/1/address/1
```

Whereas I think SDR wants me to do

```
post /api/user/1/address 
Content-Type:text/uri-list
/api/address/1
```

But the problem is that I don't have URI for my old entity so I have to rewrite most of the project. Or don't use SDR. But I want to use SDR because going forward it saves me a lot of boiler plate code for new entity where they just need simple CRUD.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, SDR only checks the last part of the link after the last slash. So the next request is enough:

post /api/user/1/address 
Content-Type:text/uri-list
/1

(It definetely worked this way in v2.x, maybe there are stricter rules in v3.x, I didn't test it)